# Hiding a Marker in StreetView when it wouldn't be visible in the real world

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a Google Maps application (V.3) with a Street View component.  The application takes position data collected from a mobile device and displays it as a Polyline on the map and then plays a corresponding set of Street View panoramas to recreate the User's path.  As part of this, I am displaying Markers on the panorama to show the path over the next handful of steps.

This is working fine at this stage of development.  However, if a Marker is behind/within a building or around a corner, it is being rendered such that, as an example, it gives the appearance that the user is slowly climbing up the side of the building.  What I would like to do is determine if a Marker would be hidden and prevent its rendering.

I notice that when hovering over the panorama, there seems to be a kind of "wall detection" feature going on.  I haven't found a way to do this in the documentation, but is there a way to detect these walls programmically?  I have been playing around with the number of Markers to show and other strategies that work "okay", but if this is possible, it would be the best solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end? I'm experiencing a similar problem

Comment: @user2693765 Unfortunately, no.  I ended up simply limiting the number of markers that would be drawn.  There has to be a way to do this, but I have moved on to other projects and am not working on this any more.